# I cannot leave a comment now

Tags: support, comments

I could already add comments, but now I can't. I am using Firefox 11.0, tried to use IE9 but the problem persists

Comment: You can't here on Meta or on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Can you give us a link to a question where you tried to post a comment?

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Firefox. He said that

Comment: @Martin Yes, he edited it in after my comment (in the grace period, so don't bother checking the revision history, it's not there).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052675/a-sample-code-about-the-concept-interface-as-a-contract-that-describes-the , it seems using Firefox i can leave a comment in meta.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in? (With 13 rep you cannot comment here on Meta. But with your 95 rep on Stack Overflow, it should work there; see [How do comments work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).)

Comment: no , but the cookie file exists in my pc , so I could authenticated and then I asked my question and sent it to stackoverflow

Comment: @slamak you have to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on comments: you're not logged in.

Login is necessary to do everything based on reputation. Cookies aren't enough

Comment: I could ask and send a a question , but i can leave a comment wooow , u think its a normal thing ? is this a bug or something ?

Comment: In case you were able to send a question, you WERE logged in

Comment: I'm happy Martin seems to understand your above comment, but I really don't, @siamak.

Comment: exactly in that time i coudnt add comments ,but i can see my profile , ok please tell me how its possible to sign out i cant find any option to sign out  , do i have to delete the history of firefox ?

Comment: You have to hover over your name at the topbar and hit "Log out" and "log out" once again on the page you're redirected to

Comment: things are so complicated , i can see what u said in meta.stackoverflow.com but I cant see such a thing in stackoverflow.com , it seems my browser dosen't run the script related to the options window :( anyway thank u very much

Comment: Clear cache, cookies. It should unlog you and (maybe) log you back. Try it

Comment: I cleared whole my history, catch, and cookies but the problem still exists! I can leave a comment here but not on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468810/start-ics-emulator-without-menu-button and some other pages of this website/froum. Whats wrong?